# vbscript excel constant values e.g. HorizontalAlignment = -4108

Tags: vbscript, constants

Does anyone know if there is a list somewhere of all the vbscript value constants

e.g.
HorizontalAlignment = -4108

thanks

Comment: it's only Excel'97, but maybe it can help: http://techsupt.winbatch.com/ts/T000001033005F9.html

Comment: That's great the ones i'm familiar with still look valid - Thank you

Comment: That link gives me error 404 now - i guess that page got removed!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in an Excel forum and here are the replies to that thread that help a bit...

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/651263-vbscript-excel-constant-values.html